# VSFTPD - How to jail users in his own dir

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I want to "jail" the user in his respective directory but they are being jailed at /var/www having permissions to "walk" and write in any directory at www.

**Vsftpd on CentOS 7** - System details:

SITE 1:

```
Path: /var/www/site1
Owner and group:  site1:site1
/home/site1 is a symbolic link to /var/www/site1
```

SITE 2:

```
Path: /var/www/site2
Owner and group:  site2:site2
/home/site2 is a symbolic link to /var/www/site2
```

My /etc/passwd:

```
[...]
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/usr/share/httpd:/sbin/nologin
site1:x:1000:1000::/var/www/./site1:bin/bash
php-fpm:x:995:992:php-fpm:/var/lib/php/fpm:/sbin/nologin
site2:x:1001:1001::/var/www/./site2:/bin/bash
```

My /etc/vsftpd/vsfptd.conf:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
xferlog_enable=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES

chroot_local_user=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/$USER ### also tried: local_root=/home/$USER
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
passwd_chroot_enable=YES
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=10100
pasv_min_port=10090
force_dot_files=YES
```

I also have disabled SELinux, with enabled it's impossible to access ftp using windows(even in active mode).

Anyone can see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, guys! The problem was the dot in home path of /etc/passwd.

Before(Not working):

```
site1:x:1000:1000::/var/www/./site1:bin/bash
```

Now(working):

```
site1:x:1000:1000::/var/www/site1:bin/bash
```